# Friend operator in code example? C++ header file, what is friend doing here?

Tags: c++, operators

I am looking over some code and I was wondering what the friend operator is doing in this class header file.

Is this just needed to say that "when I am using this operator and both inputs are of type CSegment3D, I operate on them in the way defined in the function implementation"?

```
class CSegment3D : public CObject
{
public:
    CSegment3D& operator*=(const double& factor);//  multiply by a scalar factor & assign
    CSegment3D& operator/=(const double& factor);//  divide by a scalar factor & assign
    CSegment3D& operator+=(const CSegment3D& other);// vector addition
    CSegment3D& operator-=(const CSegment3D& other);// vector subtraction
    friend CSegment3D GetMidpoint(const CSegment3D& ptA, const CSegment3D& ptB);
    friend CSegment3D GetNormal( CSegment3D *pSeg1, CSegment3D *pSeg2, CSegment3D *pSeg3 ); // Return a point normal to the surface defines by the tree point passed in.
    friend double operator*(const CSegment3D& vectorA, const CSegment3D& vectorB); // dot product
    friend CSegment3D operator*(const double& factor, const CSegment3D& vectorA); // multiply by a scalar
    friend CSegment3D operator/(const CSegment3D& vectorA, const double& factor); // divide by a scalar
    friend CSegment3D operator+(const CSegment3D& vectorA, const CSegment3D& vectorB);// vector addition
    friend CSegment3D operator-(const CSegment3D& vectorA, const CSegment3D& vectorB );// vector subtraction
    friend CSegment3D operator^(const CSegment3D& vectorA, const CSegment3D& vectorB); // cross product
    friend CSegment3D operator%(CSegment3D vectorA, const CSegment3D& vectorB); // projection of vectorB onto vectorA
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I always like to tell my students, friend is like a girlfriend: functions with friend keywords aren't family, but still get access to your most beloved things, in this case, your "private" attributes

Comment: Imperfect analogy: `friend`s aren't mutual ;)

Comment: @milleniumbug: Not all boyfriend/girlfriends commit in the same way to a relationship...

Comment: @mah: As with friend keyword goes, my girlfriend gets to see all my privates.... I can have many girlfriends (just like friend functions), and, just like friend functions, the more girlfriends you've, the unsafer you're and easier to make errors :)

Comment: @milleniumbug: Girlfriends aren't mutual either. When YOU want to access their privates, usually (agree that friend functions are ALWAYS), you get an 'Sorry dear, got headache tonight' exception :P

Answer (score 1):

The keyword friend is used to allow a function access private members of a class even when the function is not a member of that class. The friendship is declared within the class definition, but the functions still aren't members of that class and need to be declared and defined elsewhere.

So for example `friend CSegment3D GetMidpoint(const CSegment3D& ptA, const CSegment3D& ptB);` in the class definition means that the function `GetMidpoint(const CSegment3D& ptA, const CSegment3D& ptB)` can access private members of CSegment3D even though it's not a member function of that class.

Comment: But why can they not do it already? They are defined in CSegment3D does that not give them access to all fields of its own class?

Comment: @BumSkeeter I expanded my answer to clarify that.

Comment: Ok so it is there so "Class A" could initialize and then add two CSegment3D objects even though it is not of class CSegment3D?

Comment: in your example GetMidpoint() is not  a member function of CSegment3D, but a free function. Another hint for that is the fact that it requires 2 CSegment3Ds as parameters - not just the other one as it would if it was part of a CSegment3D. Additionally, having operators not as members is actually advisable for symmetry reasons (see Scott Meyers Effective C++ or More Effective C++ - I don't recall which)

Comment: Whether the operator is a public member function or a free function doesn't affect where that operator can be called from. The friendship is required for the operator function itself to access private class members if the operator is a free function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another, more technical (and boring) sample/answer:

```
    // Point2D.h
    class Point2D() {
    private:
        float x,y;
    public:
                float GetX_Method() const;
                // Next one is a function, so cant add const at end
        friend  float GetX_FriendFunction(const Point2D &p); 
    }



    //Point2D.cpp

    float Point2D::GetX_Method() const {
        return x; // Since this method belongs to a point, C++ knows where to find x
    }


    float GetX_FriendFunction(const Point2D &p) {
        // This is a friend function. Itdoesn't belong to the class
        // but still can access private members of objects created from that
        // class. All we need is the object itself (p in this case)
        return p.x; 
    }

    // This one isn't either method nor friend
    float GetX_NoFriendFunction(const Point2D &p) {
        // This will give an error since x is private
        return p.x;
    }


    // main.cpp

    main() {
        Point2D p1;

        // Prints P1 X. P1 is implicitly given by calling function
        cout << p1.GetX_Method() << endl;        
        // Prints P1 X. P1 must be given as parameter 
        cout << GetX_FriendFunction(p1) << endl; 
        // This one throws error, since it can access private members of P1
        cout << GetX_NoFriendFunction(p1) << endl; 
    }


// NOTES: 
// * As you may guess, it's the class who says 'You're my friend', otherwise,
// anyone could access other's code and make bad things.
// 
// * If you abuse friendship, you'll end up working as with C and structs
// 
// * Typical use of friend are operators. For example, inside Point2D, you
// could write:


    // This one will allow us to multiply one float to both X and Y
    // and will be called this way:
    // 
    // p1 = p1 * 5.0f; // Also p1 = p1.operator*(5.0f);
    //
    // Notice operator* only accepts float number. Point is implicitly given
    Point2D operator*(float n); 

    // Now think about this one:
    //
    // p1 = 5.0f * p1;
    //
    // Mathematically it's the same, but following same rules than before,
    // you must go to "float" class to add the operator* function, which is,
    // of course, not possible :) so this is what you do
    friend Point2D operator*(float left_operator, const Point2D& right_operator);
    // That way, you use a friend function for do the same job


    // Anyway, as said, you must avoid using friend as much as possible.
    // This problem
    // 
    // p1 = 5.0f * p1;
    //
    // Could have been solved without using friend using a plain C function
    // like this:
    Point2D operator*(float left_operator, const Point2D& right_operator)
    {
        // Gotta love how easy is to get my work done by others in C++
        return right_operator*left_operator; 
    }
```